# Linux Ping на неверный адрес

Tags: linux, shell, ping

Делаю команду пинг на локальный компьютер, который точно знаю что включен в сеть

и в ответ странный ответ

```
root@lbp2:/home/alex# ping 192.168.1.192
PING 192.168.1.192 (192.168.1.192) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.20 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

пингую 192.168.1.192,
а в ответе 192.168.1.20,
почему такое может происходить? какие симптомы?

Comment: `192.168.1.20` — это ip-адрес, закреплённый за тем сетевым интерфейсом, с которого отправляются пакеты. `Destination Host Unreachable` — ну, переведите это с английского.

Answer (score 0):

как уже ответили в комментарии это ваш IP в подсетке. Хост который вы пытаетесь пинговать не найден.